# how to pass a function with callback type in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

say for example I have a custom text field class like this

```
class CustomTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function onSubmit;

  CustomTextField({
    required this.onSubmit,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      onSubmitted: (value) => onSubmit(value),
    );
  }
}
```

as you can see, I need to pass a function to get the submitted text string value from text field. and I can use it like this

```
CustomTextField (onSubmit: () {
   print("something");
})
```

but I don't have any error when I write my code like that. what I want is like this

```
CustomTextField (onSubmit: (myValue) { // <--- if I don't write 'myValue' in here it will have error
   print(myValue);
})
```

I want my code to give me error if I don't write a variable name (string) inside the parentheses

how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the type of `onSubmit` from a general function to a function that takes in a String parameter like so.

```
final Function(String value) onSubmit;
```

Comment: should also specify the return as void: